# The system cannot find the file specified when backup the database

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to backup my sql database. I try use this first

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Process.Start("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Thesis\BACKUP feb 15\capstone_real\capstone_real\Resources\mysqldump.exe", " -u root -padmin capstone -r ""C:\Users\user\Desktop\Thesis\backup1.sql""")

End Sub
```

it works.. but I didn't want to specified the directory like this so try this

```
     Process.Start(" " & Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\mysqldump.exe,  -u root -padmin capstone -r ""C:\Users\user\Desktop\Thesis\backup2.sql""")
```

Didn't work (The system cannot find the file specified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Points to Note

1. `Application.StartupPath` returns path like `C:\ xyz derectories\bin\debug`
2. Verify the `debug` folder contains required Directory
3. If every thing is fine still not getting work then this may happen because of initial space added to `Application.StartupPath`

Comment: Thanks sir. I forgot the Application.StartupPath will go to the debug folder hehe.